# Can a Python Module Access Global Variables where it is Imported?

Tags: python

I have a python file, say it's called `foo.py`, which is simply the three lines of code

```
x = 0
def bar():
    return globals()
```

Now, when I open the python terminal and run

```
from foo import bar
x=1
bar()["x"]
```

I intend to see 1 but I instead see 0. **Is there any way to achieve my intended behavior?**

I've found plenty of resources online about *changing* global variables, but in this case I only want to *access* a global variable.

Comment: You have to import `x` too.

Comment: `import foo; foo.x=1`?

Comment: Globals are global *within a module*. There’s no global globals. No, your intended behavior is not possible.

Comment: I see. I imagined that gloabls() would be called whenever bar() is in the current environment. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: If you really mean "exactly one frame out", you can do `inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_globals` which is just `sys._getframe(2).f_globals`

Comment: but as a general rule for dealing with frames, **always clear frames manually to avoid reference cycles**

Comment: The help for `globals` indicates that it "returns the dictionary containing the **current scope's** global variables" (emphasis mine). The globals for `foo.bar` are the globals for `foo`, regardless of where `bar` is called. This is because Python (like most programming languages) uses *static* (or lexical) scoping.

Comment: (Even if you *mean* exactly one frame out, you shouldn’t actually *do* that. Write normal, non-magic code.)

Comment: That's completely fair. I was hoping to write a helper function for future personal use, and got to wondering how lazy it was possible to be. I absolutely appreciate that, even if I could do this, it would still be bad practice.

Comment: What is your _actual_ intended behaviour, though? Because I can't think of a reason why this pattern would make sense. What are you trying to achieve that you think this code is going to let you do?

Comment: It just saves me the keystrokes of specifying a value -- which I will always call `x` -- that I'll want to pass to the same helper function in many future cases.

Comment: The idea is to be able to call `helper_function()` instead of `helper_function(same_variable_name_across_many_different_projects=x)`

Answer (score 1):

Consider your main code:

```py
from foo import bar
x=1
bar()["x"]
```

The second line, `x=1` will create a global variable `x` in your main code. This variable is not the same as the one in foo.py.

If you want to change the global variable `x` in foo.py, then do this:

```py
import foo

foo.x = 1
```

That means you don't even need the function `bar()` at all.

If you still want to use a function to set the `foo.x` variable, then you can modify foo.py as follow:

```py
# foo.py
x = 0

def setx(value):
    global x
    x = value

def getx():
    global x
    return x
```

Then in the main code:

```py
import foo

print(foo.getx())  # 0
foo.setx(1)
print(foo.getx())  # 1
```

That being said, I still like the first approach as it is much simpler and more direct.